# ubuntu shows my partitions on the launcher but it cant find my hardrive while trying to install the OS

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I formatted my (Hp Envy h8 PC series) into two partitions of fat32 500gb on a msdos boot table and changed my SATA emulation to AHCI. then turned off secure boot and enabled legacy support. Ubuntu sees my hard drive and puts it on the launcher and folder menu but when I start the ubuntu installer it cant find my hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to create an Ubuntu-only system, then there's no need to create partitions before you install Ubuntu; the Ubuntu installer can handle the partitioning all by itself. The actions you describe may result in what appears to be an *empty disk,* but that's different from *not recognizing the disk at all.* Please clarify which is the case.

If the disk appears empty, and if you want an Ubuntu-only system, just proceed and let the Ubuntu installer create partitions (or create them manually yourself if you have reason to deviate from the Ubuntu defaults).

If the Ubuntu installer claims you have no hard disk installed, then that most likely means that your disk is too new for your kernel. If you're trying to install a relatively old version of Ubuntu, using a more recent version might help. If your hardware is *very* new (meaning the design, not necessarily when the machine was built), you might have to wait or use a plug-in card (if it's a desktop model) to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot install to a fat32 filesystem.  Delete one and leave free space for the Ubuntu installer.  The installer will make a root and a swap by default, and if you want, you may select a fourth partition for /home.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out all i had to do was go in the terminal and type`sudo dmraid -rE`